# Enable PECL HTTP in Kohana PHP framework

Tags: php, http, kohana, kohana-3, kohana-3.2

I'm totally new to kohana framework and I downloaded and installed kohana 3.2.2 version which is latest stable version.
But when i run the install.php it pass all the requirements but not this requirement.

PECL HTTP Enabled   Kohana can use the http extension for the Request_Client_External class.

I want PECL HTTP Enabled Pass , because in my website there will be more http request coming from other sites.

Could anyone help me to install Kohana with this PECL HTTP Enabled.
I'm using a windows and install kohana in WAMP server www/kohana folder.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need PECL enabled (actually there is no official build for Windows), just make sure you have cURL enabled and Kohana will be able to make requests anyway.